# C# UWP SpeechRuntime.exe memory leak?

Tags: c#, uwp, memory-leaks, speech-recognition, windows-10-iot-core

On my dragonboard 410c with the latest Windows IoT Core build, i have some strange memory behavior. I'm running one application 24/7. But after some time, the devie does restart because of an OOM-Exception. Now i checked my code over the last few days and saw no issue there, regarding the memory usage. Then i looked into the running processes details page on the Windows Device Portal. I saw that the "SpeechRuntime.exe" is taking up more and more memory over time and does not release it at anytime. So is there some sort of issue? I'm ussing speechservices inside my app (SpeechRecognizer), so does that cause the issue of high memory usage over time?

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Are you using any types that that needs to be explicitly disposed, especially something that is running in a loop

Comment: You mean regarding speechrecognizer or in general?

Comment: From a general debugging stance

Comment: Not that i know of. But if so, why does the SpeechRuntime.exe take more and more memory then, and not the app itself?

Comment: Could you please tell me you used method Dispose to dispose the SpeechRecognizer object and releases resources used during the session?
Dispose method performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.

Comment: I'm using continuous recognation, so it has to listen all the time for speech commands, that's why i can't dispose it. Or do i make something wrong that way?

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion?